# Is it possible to configure any domain for a realm in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

Would it be possible to modify the keycloak url to which an app redirects to login? For example:

```
https://accounts.domain.com/auth?...
```

be the equivalent to:

```
https://keycloak.domain.com/auth/realms/:realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?...
```

Comment: This is configured in your app. Do you use any keycloak adapter in it?

Comment: I use angular-keycloak, but this redirect to `https://keycloak.domain.com/auth/realms/:realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?...` when login required